# Nomad : Health Check

Tags: nginx, consul, nomad

need help I have this

```
service {
  name = "nginx"
  tags = [ "nginx", "web", "urlprefix-/nginx" ]
  port = "http"
  check {
    type = "tcp"
    interval = "10s"
    timeout = "2s"
  }
}
```

how can i add a health for a specific URI if it returns a 200 response
like localhost:8080/test/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as adding another check configured to use an `http` check like so where `/health` is served by your nginx on its published port:

```
service {
  name = "nginx"
  tags = [ "nginx", "web", "urlprefix-/nginx" ]
  port = "http"
  check {
    type = "tcp"
    interval = "10s"
    timeout = "2s"
  }
  check {
    type = "http"
    path = "/health"
    interval = "10s"
    timeout  = "2s"
  }
}
```

You can see a full example here:
https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/index.html

Comment: If you do not specify a port it defaults to what?